# Post FormData (key, value): controller not receiving value when string

Tags: c#, typescript, fetch, aurelia, aurelia-fetch-client

The description for `FormData.append()` reads as follows:

> (method) FormData.append(name: **string**, value: **string** | Blob, fileName?: **string**):void

The function below is simply just appending two string literals to a `FormData` object and posting it to a C# controller. The issue is that my controller is receiving the **key** but not the **value**.

I can successfully get a **key** and **value** when my **value** is a blob, such as file data. But I cannot get the **value** when it is a string (or string literal, as shown in the demo below). It is simply empty.

```
deleteSelectedFiles(url, data, files, method = "POST") {
    var that = this;
    let formData = new FormData();

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        formData.append("test", "wow");
    }
    console.log(formData);
    return this.http.fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        body: formData,
        headers: new Headers()
    }).then(response => response.json()
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                that.refreshTable();
            }
            else {
                console.log("upload() response: " + response);
            }
        }));
}
```

I have the following **Http Fetch Client** that I've been using to do many different kinds of tasks without any issues, so I don't believe the issue is with the configuration.

```
http = new HttpClient();
http.configure(config => {
        config
        .useStandardConfiguration()
        .withBaseUrl(``);
```